# Reporting a bug when you don't know where the problem is

Tags: bug-reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Since I installed 12.04 my laptop (HP EliteBook 2760p) my computer started to hang occasionally. When this happens the screen freezes, music hangs ("Waltzing Matildaaaaaaaaaaaaa[etc]") and there's nothing I can do but turn it off by holding the power button.
Before, running 11.10, I didn't get a single crash in about 5 months.

I'd love to report the bug but just don't know where to start. I don't know which programme causes the crash, cannot reproduce it when I want to, and even can't find any reference to the crash in the system logs (kern.log nor syslog).

I suspect the Intel graphics chip, it has given me issues ever since I installed 12.04. A bug or two for this chip can be found on Launchpad. `lspci` gives me:

```
    VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

All updates are applied.

Does anyone have any good ideas? Where can I start to try and fix or report the problem? Let me know if you'd like to see any files.
I'll keep a list below of the things I try.

1. Reinstall Ubuntu, removing all hidden (.*) folders and files from my /home folder before running set-up
2. Do a memory check, just to be sure. No errors encountered in a single run.

The following is still on my to do list:

3. Try the magic combination: ALT+Printscreen, while holding them pressing R S E I U O (see http://techspalace.blogspot.com.au/2008/07/magicsysrq-keys.html)
4. Try to approach the computer through SSH